# How using pytest reuse and execute whole test method

Tags: python, pytest

I have test method:

```
@parameterized.expand("some text")
@pytest.mark.page1
def test_ccc(self):
    self.ui_step()
    self.ui(_)
    self.assertEqual()
```

and want it to be executed in my next test before execution:

```
@parameterized.expand("some text second")
@pytest.mark.page2
def next_test(self):
    test_ccc()
    self.login()
    self.assert()
```

How to do that? I tryed fixtures but it is notworking.

Comment: Why do you need to rerun the `test_ccc`?

Comment: This looks like a class - you should be able to just do `self.test_ccc()`

Comment: @Niel Godfrey Ponciano cus test_ccc create some User which I need in a next_test

Comment: @match I thought about this.

Comment: I think I will merge those two tests in one...

Comment: Use a fixture for the part that has to be done in both tests. If that does not work, show us what you have done and what you got.